# Automatically populate dates with no data

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, autofill

wondered if I could get some advice please?

If you see in the example of figures there are dates for January.

Before

[image]

What I'd like to do is create a full vector of January dates including dates with no figures so the final outcome would look like this.

After

[image]

So far all I can do is just insert lines which is a bit time consuming?
Is there formula in Excel which will automatically create date?

Many thanks

Comment: Doable with `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: Do you need the dates which are present along with the missing dates as well? Or as said above `SEQUENCE()` function can return a range of dates. Also I saw in the month of `Jan` you have instead of `3rd Jan` you have `3rd March` is that a typo?

Comment: If am not wrong could you try this once. `=LET(
a,A2:B11,
b,INDEX(a,1,1),
c,MONTH(b),
d,YEAR(b),
e,SEQUENCE(DAY(DATE(d,c,0)),,b),
HSTACK(e,XLOOKUP(e,INDEX(a,,1),INDEX(a,,2),"")))` where `A2:B11` refers to your `Before` Screenshot

Comment: Sorry i misread your question. You can actually return a range of dates using `SEQUENCE()` function. Thought you would be needing those numbers as well.

Comment: Many thanks for your help everyone.  This problem has stumped me for a while.  Have a good day:)

Answer (score 3):

Since I have commented above, posting it here as well. If you just need to return a full vector of January Dates. Then try just using `SEQUENCE()` function as mentioned by **[BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben)** Sir.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H4`

```
=SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(H2,0)),,H2)
```

---

Where: `H2 = 6/1/2023`

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(
     a,A2:B11,
     b,INDEX(a,1,1),
     c,MONTH(b),
     d,YEAR(b),
     e,SEQUENCE(DAY(DATE(d,c,0)),,b),
     VSTACK({"Date","Number"},
     HSTACK(e,XLOOKUP(e,INDEX(a,,1),INDEX(a,,2),""))))
```

---

Easy to read and understand when you define the variables using a `LET()` function.

---

Answer (score 2):

To spill result at once:

```
=HSTACK(DATE(2023,1,SEQUENCE(31,1,1,1)),XLOOKUP(DATE(2023,1,SEQUENCE(31,1,1,1)),A1:A4,B1:B4,"",0))
```

Result:

[image]

Or you could write starting date in `D1` and drag it down, then use `=XLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$A$4,$B$1:$B$4,"",0)` in `E1` and also drag it down. Result:
[image]

Comment: Or more dynamic on the month: `=let(range,A1:B4,m,1&month(@range)&year(@range),seq,sequence(eomonth(m),,m),hstack(seq,iferror(vlookup(seq,range,2,0),"")))` (untested)